# Intermittent Wi-Fi connection from Win 10 Laptop to Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, remote, headless

This morning I was able to wirelessly Remote Desktop (learned from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDqQIDL3LKg) into Raspberry Pi 3 from Win 10 Laptop

Then the connectivity broke off. No problem, I unplugged and plugged Raspberry Pi to its power source.

Just now (it is evening) wi-fi connectivity to Raspberry broke off again. I unplugged and plugged Raspberry. I rebooted my Laptop.

Nothing.

Finally I connected to Raspberry via Ethernet. Once I unplugged Ethernet, then I could sustain Wi-fi connectivity (it's been 5 minutes)

Why is this happening and how to fix?

Configured `wpa_supplicant.conf` based on https://desertbot.io/blog/headless-raspberry-pi-3-bplus-ssh-wifi-setup

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETWORK-NAME"
    psk="NETWORK-PASSWORD"
}
```

Comment: Please include the settings you've changed or commands you've issued to access your RPi from a remote laptop. A video is not a good way to show what you've done. Are you using `ssh` or something else?

Comment: Do you do exactly the same then described on the official site [Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)? If so then it's not a problem of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Will follow up in a few day